# mu4e with second account with a different stream type fails to send messages

Tags: smtpmail, ssl

I use Emacs and mu4e for email. I successfully set up Amazon WorkMail IMAP with Emacs and mu4e as a second account. My first account works with TLS:

```el
(setq ; ...
      smtpmail-smtp-server         "smtp.server.com"
      message-send-mail-function   'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
      smtpmail-auth-credentials ; ...
)
```

I was unable to set up SMTP: [Amazon's page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP_client.html) mentions that STARTTLS is not supported. I followed [this page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SendingMail) on SSL:

```el
(defvar my-mu4e-account-alist
  '(
    ("mainAccount" ; ...
     )
    ("AWS"
     (user-mail-address "me@domain.com")
     (smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.mail.eu-west-1.awsapps.com")
     (smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl)
     (smtpmail-smtp-service 465)
     )
    ))
```

And I get this error:

```
open-network-stream: Invalid connection type ssl
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this fix](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4669) of removing the quote from `'ssl`:

> The actual problem is that the list of items in mu4e-account-alist is already quoted, so when one writes (smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl), what is actually being stored in smtpmail-stream-type is literally the value 'ssl, while it should simply be ssl. Remove the extraneous quote-mark and all is well.

So, in my case, this worked:

```el
(defvar my-mu4e-account-alist
  '(
    ("mainAccount" ; ...
     )
    ("AWS"
     (user-mail-address "me@domain.com")
     (smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.mail.eu-west-1.awsapps.com")
     (smtpmail-stream-type ssl)
     (smtpmail-smtp-service 465)
     )
    ))
```